# После инициализации карты в приложении Vue.js не исполняется код

Tags: vue.js, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Инициализирую карту в приложении Vue. Карта инициализируется, но Javascript-код перестает исполняться после инициализации карты. По ссылке накидал пример инициализации.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n585r6968m

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько замечаний:

1. Инициализировать скрипты лучше в mounted а не created т.е. когда компонент уже попал в DOM.
2. Код не исполняется далее т.к. там на самом деле выходит ошибка, если обернете в `try {} catch (err) { console.log(err.toString())}` увидите ошибку `TypeError: s is not a constructor` - по этому дальнейший код и не выполняется.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку из `try {} catch`. Оказывается картам не хватало времени на загрузку всех компонентов после срабатывания события `load` скрипта. Добавил setTimeout перед запуском коллбека инициализации и все заработало. Спасибо